Why do most Democrats think Obama did a better job than Biden?
This is based on the poll in this question.

Obama is perceived as the better president by many more Democrats than Clinton & Biden, in fact more Democrats think the Republican Reagan was a better president than Biden. Why?
I can imagine two basic kinds of reasons: those based on policy (e.g. "Obama did so-and-so and Biden did not"), and those based on public perception (e.g. this). I am most interested in the first, but will accept an answer based on the second if there's indication it's the dominant reason.

How is this supposed to attract anything but opinions? There are tons of differences between the two, in their personality, the times in which they acted, the political environment, etc, all of which someone could see as relevant or not. Why would there even be a dominant reason shared by most Democrats?

@MisterMiyagi if I knew the reason, I wouldn't have to ask the question; if I don't know the reason, then I have no idea what form the answer will take and therefore do not know if it'll attract anything but opinions.

The fact that Reagan, the man that dismantled the unions and put an end to the era where working hard meant earning more money, giving birth to the actual days of billionaires and beggars and extreme unequality and polarization, is credited with being a great president, both from Reps and Dems, will tell you everything you need to know about polls and politics in general. This is a popularity contest, it's not based on merit or facts, just on how well different personalities connected with the average american.

Btw. if A is seen better than B is doesn't mean that B is bad. The difference between A and B could also be very small or both could be very good. Better would be if the performance was graded and then compared.

I'll try to find some actual polls or panels on this [why Q], but one thing to remember was that Biden won in 2020 largely on the argument that he is not Trump, IIRC. (E.g. just revisit the 1st Trump-Biden televised debate back in 2020.) So that in a sense defined his image, no matter what else he did: the 'stand-in' guy whom was disliked by slightly fewer people than Trump.

Also, some people forget, but Obama [or rather the Dems 'under' him] suffered a "shellacking" in the 2010 midterms, something that didn't happen nearly to the same extent in 2022. https://edition.cnn.com/2023/07/13/politics/obama-biden-reelection-what-matters/index.html

FWTW, in the words one historian "voters viewed [Biden] as a placeholder, and he could never transcend the text of his speeches to visually “embody the spirit of the nation with a sense of verve, energy and optimism.”" https://apnews.com/article/biden-political-legacy-presidential-election-5aee4f47ecb317d4f6ef2a2148eba1d8 And the piece is also rather correct that Obama was iconified for the change he stood for, elections-wise at least.

For starters Obama has a complete 8 year record to look at and Biden only has a partial 3 year record to look at. Not to mention that how people/history view a presidency changes over time and if you ask this question again in 8 years when Biden is no longer the active president the results could be different.

In my opinion, not that difficult.  One had 2 consecutive runs, few crisis, passed health care reforms, was widely popular.  The other had to bail on a 2nd run due to health issues, was unexpectedly weak on reelection chances vs Trump, presided during a global inflation bout, had to sink resources into Ukraine, gets pushed from the lefty Dem wing (which Obama didn't) and finally, is getting fallout from the Gaza war.  My opinion only and opinions are all this Q can get unless a specific poll is found that asked exactly this Q.  Look at the 2 opinion-driven answers for confirmation.  VTC.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica 1) The poll was done in 2023, hence statements like The other had to bail on a 2nd run due to health issues are inapplicable 2) You should downvote the answers, not the question. VTR.

Looking at that question, it seems what they ended up measuring was mainly presentation style. Obama and Reagan were both sophisticated orators. Trump and Clinton, while nowhere near as eloquent as the first two, were both good showman: aharp, engaging, extemporaneous speakers. Both have lost that edge in recent years, I think, but that's not relevant to this. Biden and both Bushes were mediocre speakers at best, given to hackneyed phrases, obvious posturing, goofy humor, and un-enthralling styles.
Biden's accomplishments in one term — like them or hate them — equalled or surpassed what anyone else on this list managed. He is an extremely able president. He'll be remembered for that by historians, I'm sure, but that kind of prosaic, practical competence doesn't register with workaday citizens, who tend to be more focussed on charisma.

"Biden's accomplishments in one term — like them or hate them — equalled or surpassed what anyone else on this list managed." Maybe so: I could certainly point to a few, but I could do the same for the other Democratic presidents. Perhaps you could provide some information in the answer to roughly quantify how the major accomplishments of the Biden administration measure up to those of the Obama administration, for instance.

@Obie2.0 What you ask for is beyond the scope of this question, probably even the scope of a single question. One could probably write a whole thesis comparing Biden and Obama alone. Obama was strong in healthcare, Biden was very strong in the environment and general economy and containing Russia. But really, books will be written about that probably.

This is possible (and you might be able to find presidents rated by charisma to correlate with these figures). But it could also be that charismatic presidents are more likely to get things done.

@Obie2.0: Every administration makes a list of their self-perceived accomplishments. I don't know where to look for that off hand, but a google search should find it. Presidential historians also make lists, which end up in history books and in the periodically updated presidential rankings. These include both accomplishments and charisma, but I'm sure if you dug into the details they'd give a decent breakdown.

@Obie2.0: In the latter, Biden is currently ranked marginally below Clinton, somewhat above Reagan, and well above both Bushes and Trump. Only Obama beats him significantly, and I suspect that's because Obama's successes, while seemingly fewer, were more dramatic and contested than Biden's.

@StuartF: No offense, but if you honestly believe that talking a good game correlates positively with competence, you might want to think on that. I know too many people who can talk the stars out of the sky that I wouldn't trust to watch my dog for weekend. Just sayin'…

Obamacare probably had the most direct effect on the populace. So he was a charismatic leader and he did something good that most people benefitted from. Currently, people associate Biden with inflation. He did get us past covid, but the Inflation Reduction Act and the infrastructure bill don't really resonate with voters.
